# Self oil changes on warranty

Tags: oil-change, warranty

I have a 2014 Kia Rio. I have been doing my own oil changes since after the first one by the dealer.

I have not kept the receipts to the oil I have purchased.

If something goes wrong down the road can I be denied warranty service because of holes in my maintenance record?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about local legislation

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on where you live. The major thing is did you keep record of when you did the oil changes and what the mileage was at the time. Also, if the warranty item in question has nothing to do with scheduled maintenance, there is not issue whatsoever. **Here in the US, yes they can deny you warranty coverage for your vehicle if you cannot prove the maintenance schedule has been done.** They cannot, however, deny you the right to do maintenance on your own vehicle.

Again, this applies to the US only. Other countries have their own laws.

Comment: So what constitutes a maintenance schedule? Can I not just fill a sheet with date retroactively, and call it a maintenance schedule?

Comment: @ScottF - You can do whatever you like. The maintenance schedule is what's set forth by the manufacturer. It's the "change your oil every 3K/3months" type thing. You can find it in your owner's manual.

Comment: So basically I don't need to keep any receipts at all, and can just make up a fake maintenance schedule if something happens to my engine that requires maintenance?

Comment: @ScottF Probably not if you don't delete that comment, lol.

Comment: @P Here you can cite this in your answer if you want: https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0138-auto-warranties-routine-maintenance It's slightly more complicated but same general idea.